# $N \to N \rtimes G \to G$ is an extension of $G$ by $N.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exact-sequence, semidirect-product

Let $(G,.)$ and $(H,.)$ be two groups and $\phi:G \to \text{Aut}(N)$ be a group homomorphism. On the set $N \times G$ define a binary operation by: $(m,g)(n,h)=(m (\phi(g)(n)),gh)$ and we donote the set $N \times G$ with this binary operation as $N \rtimes G.$  I have shown that $N \rtimes G$ is a group.

> I have to show that$\require{AMScd}$
>   \begin{CD}N @>{i}>> N \rtimes G @>{\pi} >> G \\\end{CD} is an extension of $G$ by $N,$ where $i: N \to N \rtimes G$ defined by $n \mapsto (n,e_{G})$ and $\pi: N \rtimes G \to G$ is defined by $(n,g) \mapsto g.$ What I exactly have to show ?

Clearly $i$ is an injection and $\pi$ is a surjection. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You have to show that the above sequence, with $1$‘s added at both ends, is exact.

Comment: So the composition is clearly identity. And any element in the kernel of $\pi$ is of the form $(n,e_{G})$ so clearly it is $i(n).$ My question is am I to show only exactness or split exact ?

Comment: You only need to show exactness. You'd get a split exact sequence iff the extension is trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**All** you have to show is that

(1) Ker$(i)=1$

(2)  Ker$(\pi)$ is the image of $N$ under $i$

(3) $\pi $ is surjective

As you have said these are relatively obvious results